# How can I animate a text to seamlessly scroll horizontally on my website?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am working on my coming soon website and I am lost here.

I want to make the page scroll from seamlessly from right to left and a readable pace, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  --color-text: #dedede;
  --color-bg: #060606;
  color: var(--color-text);
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
}

.hero {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 10vh 0 25vh;
  --marquee-width: 100vw;
  --offset: 20vw;
  --move-initial: calc(-25% + var(--offset));
  --move-final: calc(-50% + var(--offset));
  --item-font-size: 8vw;
  counter-reset: hero;
}

.marquee {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--marquee-width);
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}

.marquee__inner {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), -0, 0);
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.marquee .marquee__inner {
  animation-play-state: running;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.marquee span {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: var(--item-font-size);
  padding: 0 1vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-style: regular;
  color: #FFFB00;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(var(--move-final), 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <nav class="hero">
    <div class="hero__item">
      <div class="marquee">
        <div class="marquee__inner" style="--tw: 189ch; --ad: 12s;">
          <span>Logo Design • Brand Identity • Illustration • Icon Design • UX/UI • Logo Design
              </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have tried to adjust the keyframe, and animation marquee, but I am not sure why is is not scrolling with breaks.

Here is the code on CodePenhttps://codepen.io/onuohaui/details/JjvNyaJ

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this slider to work you need to know the exact size of width.
here is my version of the slider

```css
 :root {
         --eachWidth: 250px;
         --item-font-size: 3vw;
      }

      body {
         display: grid;
         place-items: center;
         min-height: 100vh;
      }

      .slider {
         height: 200px;
         /* container width */
         width: 90%;
         position: relative;
         margin: auto;
         overflow: hidden;
         display: grid;
         place-items: center;
      }

      .slide-track {
         display: flex;
         /* slide track width = total number of slides 9*2 = 18 * individual width (250px) */
         width: calc(var(--eachWidth) * 18);
         background-color: red;
         /* control the speed */
         animation: scroll 20S linear infinite;
      }

      /*
        .slide-track:hover {
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }
      */
      @keyframes scroll {
         0% {
            transform: translateX(0)
         }

         100% {
            transform: translateX(calc(var(--eachWidth) *9 *-1))
         }
      }

      .slide {
         height: 100px;
         width: var(--eachWidth);
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         padding: 15px;
         font-size: var(--item-font-size);
         padding: 0 1vw;
         font-weight: 900;
         line-height: 1.15;
         font-style: regular;
         color: #FFFB00;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-track" id="slideTrack">
         <div class="slide">text 1</div>
         <div class="slide">text 2</div>
         <div class="slide">text 3</div>
         <div class="slide">text 4</div>
         <div class="slide">text 5</div>
         <div class="slide">text 6</div>
         <div class="slide">text 7</div>
         <div class="slide">text 8</div>
         <div class="slide">text 9</div>

         <!-- you need to add the same amount again so it appears  seamless -->

         <div class="slide">text 1</div>
         <div class="slide">text 2</div>
         <div class="slide">text 3</div>
         <div class="slide">text 4</div>
         <div class="slide">text 5</div>
         <div class="slide">text 6</div>
         <div class="slide">text 7</div>
         <div class="slide">text 8</div>
         <div class="slide">text 9</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

i also recommend that you define all css variables in the (:root)

Comment: Thank you.

I have tried this and I noticed that it doesn't work for me.

The content I have on my <div> for the slide are not like list items, but as a sentences.

Comment: cant you lower the width and separate sentences to words? so it looks like a sentence

Comment: cant you lower the width and separate sentences to words? so it looks like a sentence

Answer (score 1):

Your Variables are not working as you intent them to be. I would recommend fixing them or not use at all for a simple task like this..

`Changes:`translating the text 38% to the right with`translate: 38%;` at the start and moving it back to left 110% with`translate: -110%;` at the end of the animation.

you can easily change your text speed by increasing or decreasing the animation time.

`Lower the number faster the speed`
`Higher the number Slower the speed`

```css
:root {
  --marquee-width: 100vw;
  --offset: 20vw;
  --move-initial: calc(-25% + var(--offset));
  --move-final: calc(-50% + var(--offset));
  --item-font-size: 8vw;
  --color-text: #dedede;
  --color-bg: #060606;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--color-text);
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
}

.hero {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 10vh 0 25vh;
  counter-reset: hero;
}

.marquee {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--marquee-width);
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}

.marquee__inner {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  translate: 38%;
  animation: marquee 11s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.marquee .marquee__inner {
  animation-play-state: running;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.marquee span {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: var(--item-font-size);
  padding: 0 1vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-style: regular;
  color: #FFFB00;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    translate: 38%;
  }
  100% {
    translate: -110%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav class="hero">
    <div class="hero__item">
      <div class="marquee">
        <div class="marquee__inner" style="--tw: 189ch; --ad: 12s;">
          <span>Logo Design • Brand Identity • Illustration • Icon Design • UX/UI • Logo Design
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: so you used a blank space to hide the breaking point?